# Моя ошибка или не поддерживает два параметра?

Tags: css3, css

Эффект `transition`. Пример:

```css
div {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:#ff0000;
  transition:background 2s;
  -webkit-transition:background 2s;
  transition:width 2s;
  -webkit-transition:width 2s;
}

div:hover {
  background:#00ff00;
  width:300px;
}
```

```html
<p>Этот кот не будет прыгать на ослике</p>

<div></div>

<p>Наведение transition effect.</p>
```

На примере видно, что либо то меняется с задержкой, либо другое, если исключать их попеременно.
А как сделать, что бы они срабатывали оба? Или это только через **transition: all**?
Например:

```
transition:all 2s;
-webkit-transition:all 2s;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Или через `all`, как Bы сказали или так:

```css
div {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:#ff0000;
  transition:width 2s, background 2s;
  -webkit-transition:width 2s, background 2s;
}

div:hover {
  background:#00ff00;
  width:300px;
}
```

```html
<p>Этот кот не будет прыгать на ослике</p>

<div></div>

<p>Наведение transition effect.</p>
```